# DataGrid with ScrollViewer inside an Expander and ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, expander

I've an ItemsControl with a DataGrid inside an Expander as ItemTemplate.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItemSource}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander>
                        <Grid>
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItemSource}"
                                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                      MaxHeight="200">
                            </DataGrid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I want to have a ScrollViewer for each DataGrid and one for the list of expanders if there are too many of them. My problem is that it only works if I set the MaxHeight Property of the DataGrid. That's annoying because if there is e.g. only one entry in the ItemsControl the entry isn't using the whole space because it's height is limited.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How do you expect the inner `ScrollViewer`s to know when to add scroll bars if you don't tell it when via a `Height` property? The `Expander` will allow it to grow as big as it like otherwise.

Comment: That's why I asked. I don't know a way but maybe someone else did. Thought about a behavior which calculates the MaxHeight when there's only one entry. But maybe that's a bit awkward.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that... the inner `ScrollViewer`s won't know when to add scroll bars if you don't tell them when via setting a `Height` (or `MaxHeight` or `MinHeight`) property.

Comment: I understand that. I mentioned calculating the MaxHeight via a behavior cause when the user resized the application or there's only one entry in the ItemsControl there could be some unused white space. That's why I thought about the behavior: to calculate the MaxHeight; dependant on the Height of the outer grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, Hard to understand what you up but this might help you out futher.

The problem is the ScrollViewer. Let me show you what ScrollViewer does in WPF.

Its default behavior is to switch between whether user wishes to have ScrollBars or not.

In case the user hasnt set any preferences the ScrollViewer will try to use ScrollBars. Therefore the ScrollViewer passes infinity as value to its children to allow its children to take as much space as they want. The end result as in your case is when one item is only there it does not fullfill all available space because ScrollViewer allows it to be arranged at its desired size (which is smaller than available size). Basically in other words ScrollViewer says to children meehhh I dont care, you pick your desired size and arrange yourself at your desired size. I will just display ScrollBars so user can scroll to you. ScrollViewer is pretty dumb.

In order to recieve the fullfill space behavior you will have to tell ScrollViewer to disable ScrollBar. Then the ScrollViewer will not pass infinity as measure value to its children but instead it will pass the size of your window/available space. The children will notice that a fix width and height is there (and not infinity) and will measure themselves to fullfill the given space. (Means children desired size will be windows size or size of available spcae and not the one they wishes to be. The one they wishes is smaller than available space anyways)

To sum up. When you have one item, just disable ScrollBars or dont use ScrollViewer at all. Leave ScrollViewer out and just let Expander be the next node of Grid. Expander will use complete available space. Though when you notice that you added new items to your ItemsSource you just swap the template and use ScrollViewer around Expanders allowing you to scrolling.

I hope I gave you an idea at least of how to make one item take the complete size.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But if I remove the outer ScrollViewer the DataGrid is not showing a ScrollViewer. Only if I set e.g. the DataGrid-MaxHeight the DataGrid-ScrollViewer will be enabled.

Comment: I am talking about the top most ScrollViewer. What is DataGrid-ScrollViewer? The one build in?

Comment: Yes, the build in. Sorry, should have said that. 
But your idea with two templates is good. So i will set a MaxHeight when having more then one Expander. But I still need a solution for one Expander without the top most expander and only the DataGrid build in.

Comment: Ahh ok. You have to consider that Expander does almost the same as ScrollViewer except the Scrollbars. Expander doesnt pass complete window size to DataGrid. It passes infinity which indicates to DataGrid to arrange itself with its desired size and not the complete available size. When Expander is expanded it will use DataGrid's desired size. You have to tell it to use the size of Window. So maybe one template is DataGrid alone, and another is ListBox of Expanders. But use ListBox and not ItemsControl.

Comment: Ah, damnit...forgot about that expander behavior...thx :) Why ListBox and no ItemsControl? Really like the ItemsControl because I don't need selection.

Comment: I dont know your project I cant decide. ItemsControl has many methods that are virtual and only overriden in ListBox or TreeView. When you in wpf you usually wish the end users to work with end controls. ItemsControl doesnt have ScrollViewer while ListBox does. Futhermore ListBox knows how to deal with ScrollViewer. ListBox has logic implemented to know how to scroll properly and how to bring items into view. ItemsControl is a bit dumb. ListBox has a nice control template while ItemsControl has a small cheap one. Thought you can take ItemsControl. Its ok. As long it does the job. Haha